# How to perform SAML SSO login to login.microsoft.com using Python

Tags: python, automation, single-sign-on, saml

To start, I have attempted to research this quite a bit but haven't been able to find anything helpful. I am hoping to learn this quite in-depth to help share the knowledge.

Goal: I am looking for a way to programmatically log into the login.microsoftonline.com SSO using my credentials, and then save the cookies/header/authentication token for use in the scripts requests.

Scenario: I am a system user, not admin, where I have to pull and sort a bunch of metric data manually every single day. I have written scripts that grab this data already and sort it automatically. Unfortunately, every time I want to run these scripts, I have to manually log in using Chrome, use the developer console to grab the header/token information, and put those in the config file my scripts will use in order for them to successfully grab the data.

I have researched extensively on this topic and have only found solutions for Oauth tokens (I don't have this option unfortunately), Libraries for specific sites only such as Azure, Teams, Etc. I admit I may not be searching all the keywords that may lead me to the answer but I have searched all ones I know of.

I have found an option of using a GUI pop-up in my scripts and using selenium but that still requires me to manually log in each time.